# Flash vs Silverlight on Caching

Tags: silverlight, flash

As I am testing Teampulse developped in Silverlight http://www.telerik.com/team-productivity-tools.aspx I find that it seems to not cache anything as it reloads each time from scratch. Seems much slower for me than a flash app I know.

So can silverlight be speed up with caching ? Why does it seem so slower than Flash ?

if WE develop a silverlight app, how can we control caching ? Is there an API for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes silverlight can perform better with caching.  However in most cases a Silverlight application will be using the Browser HTTP stack in which case most of the responsiblity for caching choices lie with the browser settings and the cache control headers sent by the server.  Silverlight itself has little control over caching choices.

A poorly configured server can cause the browser to fail to use the cache beneficially regardless of whether Silverlight, Flash or just plain HTML is being used on the client.

Comment: Thanks but if WE develop a silverlight app, how can we control caching ? Is there an API for that ?